# stackdriver change line colour on Dashboard Graphs

Tags: stackdriver

I have a few dashboards with multiple lines on each graph, is it possible to set their colours as currently its all 50 shades of grey

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYWhb.png)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think you can assign a specific color to each line, you can click on each instance you want to monitor from the legend under the graphic to activate/deactivate them. The ones that are not selected are blurred out, so you can actually identify what you need easily. It also adjusts the graphic scale. See my screenshot, for example:

[image: Stackdriver graphic with une gke instance line selected over the other lines]